# Select all records don't meet certain conditions in a joined table

Tags: sql, mysql

Let's say we have two tables here , posts and comments, the relations is one to many, there has a field call comment_date in the comments table.

Now I am struggle to get the expected results as follow:

All the posts have no comments after a certain date, can I done this by a SQL statement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM posts p
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 1
    FROM comments c
    WHERE c.comment_date >= 'deadline'
    AND p.post_id = c.post_id
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    posts
WHERE   post_id NOT IN 
        (
        SELECT  comment_post
        FROM    comments
        WHERE   comment_date >= @deadline
        )
```

Comment: Tested , worked as good as the first one , thanks. this is clever that don't need to specified the foreign key. as I use the post_id in the comments, so if replace the comment_post with post_id, it will be a perfect answer.

Comment: NOT IN is actually optimized to NOT EXISTS in MySQL