# Checking whether conditions are met by all rows with dynamic SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, dynamic-sql

I have a table in SQL Server 2008 which contains custom validation criteria in the form of expressions stored as text, e.g.

```
StagingTableID    CustomValidation
----------------------------------
1                 LEN([mobile])<=30
3                 [Internal/External] IN ('Internal','External')
3                 ([Internal/External] <> 'Internal') OR (LEN([Contact Name])<=100)
...
```

I am interested in determining whether all rows in a table pass the conditional statement. For this purpose I am writing a validation stored procedure which checks whether all values in a given field in a given table meet the given condition(s). SQL is not my forte, so after reading [this questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/925195/select-all-records-dont-meet-certain-conditions-in-a-joined-table) this is my first stab at the problem:

```
EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT @passed = 0 WHERE EXISTS (' +
                     N'SELECT * FROM (' +
                       N'SELECT CASE WHEN ' + @CustomValidationExpr + N' THEN 1 ' +
                       N'ELSE 0 END AS ConditionalTest ' +
                       N'FROM ' + @StagingTableName +
                     N')t ' +
                     N'WHERE t.ConditionalTest = 0)'
                  ,N'@passed BIT OUTPUT'
                  ,@passed = @PassedCustomValidation OUTPUT
```

However, I'm not sure if the nested queries can be re-written as one, or if there is an entirely better way for testing for validity of all rows in this scenario?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Sorry, 2008. I'll update my question to reflect this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to reduce by at least one subquery like this:

```
EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT @passed = 0 WHERE EXISTS (' +
                       N'SELECT 1 FROM ' +  @StagingTableName +
                       N'WHERE NOT(' + @CustomValidationExpr + N')) ' +
                  ,N'@passed BIT OUTPUT'
                  ,@passed = @PassedcustomValidation OUTPUT
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is equivalent to the query above: won't the EXISTS expression be true when there is at least one row which is valid? I'm interested in finding out whether **all** values conform to the validation criteria.

Comment: Right, I misread your original query.  Adding NOT fixes this, so the expression will return true if at least one row is not valid - updated.

Answer (score 1):

Before we answer the original question, have you looked into implementing constraints?  This will prevent bad data from entering your database in the first place.  Or is the point that these must be dynamically set in the application?

```
ALTER TABLE StagingTable
    WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [StagingTable$MobileValidLength]
    CHECK (LEN([mobile])<=30)
GO

ALTER TABLE StagingTable
    WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [StagingTable$InternalExternalValid]
    CHECK ([Internal/External] IN ('Internal','External'))
GO

--etc...
```

Comment: I wouldn't.  SQL constraints would only work if the rules would very rarely change and would be set by a developer/DBA - like stuff that would break the application if it was wrong.

Comment: @NYCdotNet We don't have constraints by design. These are staging tables, and as such, they store raw imported data in an ETL process. We don't want to fail the entire process if there is invalid data on import (which is what having constraints would do). But it is a good thought (why re-write something that the engine can already figure out for itself), and in fact was my first inkling: If I could add constrains and see if they fail or succeed in my validation SP that would work, but I could not find a way to handle or check for success/failure.

Answer (score 0):

You need to concatenate the expressions together.  I agree with @PinnyM that a `where` clause is easier for full table validation.  However, the next question will be how to identify which rows fail which tests.  I'll wait for you to ask that question before answering it (ask it as a separate question and not as an edit to this one).

To create the `where` clause, something like this:

```
declare @WhereClause nvarchar(max);
select @WhereClause = (select CustomValidation+' and '
                       from Validations v
                       for xml path ('')
                      ) + '1=1'

select @WhereClause = replace(replace(@WhereClause, '&lt;', '<'), '&gt;', '>'))
```

This strange construct, with the `for xml path('')` and the double select, is the most convenient way to concatenate values in SQL Server.

Also, put together your query *before* doing the sp_executesql call.  It gives you more flexibilty:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max);
select @sql = '
select @passed = count(*)
from '+@StagingTableName+'
where '+@WhereClause
```

That is the number that pass all validation tests.  The `where` clause for the fails is:

```
declare @WhereClause nvarchar(max);
select @WhereClause = (select 'not '+CustomValidation+' or '
                       from Validations v
                       for xml path ('')
                      ) + '1=0'
```

Comment: It seems like the less-than and greater-than signs in the validation condition are being stored in the `@sql` variable as html entities `&lt;` and `&gt;`, which makes the query fail with "An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ';'." Is there a way to turn off encoding in SQL when using XML?

Comment: I don't know how to turn that off.  However, you can replace the special characters after the fact, as I've done in my edit.  The method for concatenation actually uses XML, and these (and others) are special characters in XML.